# How do I add security group for google data studio to access my amayon RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

So I have my database and I don't want it to be publicly accessed. I want to be able to access it through Google Data Studio.

Which type of connection should I allow for that?

I want to use EC2 security groups interface, not SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Google Data Studio is a SaaS application, so imagine that you would know its IPs and allow them, still anyone using GDS could connect to your DB. You don’t want this I get.

And as you are not able to know which IPs will use the application, for me your use case is not possible like this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting my RDS to "Public Access", then configuring that I can access it only from certain IP addresses, and that no other IP address can access it.

I configured that using security groups.